# pushView animation in one page iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation

i have a web based application with only one view controller. i have some shortcut buttons in my app which will load some urls. what i need is a push animation as like 
pushViewController each time when i click the shortCut buttons.

i have only one UIView .

Comment: did you check block uiviewanimation??

Comment: The correct solution for this is to wrap the view controller in a UINavigationController, then call its pushViewController: method with the other view controller.

Comment: in which u r loading webview?

Comment: @H2CO3  actually i have only one view controller. all my urls are loading in the same view. i just need an effect like push.

Comment: @bugfinder same view controller

Comment: @LithuThiruvathira no, any hope?

Comment: @NeerajNeeru it's OK if you have only one VC. Create another! (the nav controller).

Comment: without webview inside a view controller how can u load a url with in the app?

Comment: @H2CO3 but, i need to load my url all urls on same VC. ITS A ONE PAGE APP.

Comment: @bugfinder YES, WEBVIEW IS THEIR

Comment: So if you are thinking to show the view as push better to show it using animation else the only option left for creating a  navcontroller(Don't worry you will be using one view controller only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, i have found the solution myself,

push like animation for any view

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction   functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];    
[[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

thanks for your feedbacks,